# I need help to optimize a long query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table *Chron* containing the following columns:

ID | timestamp | ...

Some timestamps have been erroneously changed to a specific date D. I want to change them to the timestamp of the **nearest rows** (in terms of ID) which have not been changed. My query is:

```
UPDATE Chron as C1
SET C1.timestamp = (
                    SELECT C2.timestamp
                    FROM Chron as C2
                    WHERE C2.timestamp != D
                    AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM Chron as C3
                        WHERE ABS(C2.id - C1.id) >
                              ABS(C3.id - C1.id)
                    )
)
WHERE C1.timestamp = D
```

The problem is that my table contains more than 300K rows and this query would take a lot of time to run. How can I optimize it? I know that it is not necessary to compare a given row C1 with the whole table, but just the neighbourhood is sufficient, but the optimal size of the neighbourhood is not always the same.

Comment: Are you sure the subquery will always return a single row? Can you explain - with a small sample - what the UPDATE is going to do?

Comment: Look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=170d1f02948cdbd8a63d3166052c780b), maybe there is something useful in it.

Comment: @Akina it looks very useful, can you explain it a bit?

Comment: Records in any subquery (later - sq) are processed in sorting order set in it. 1st sq simply initializes user variable, 3rd sq calculates `id` of the closest valid record with lower `id` value, 4th sq do the same, but obtain the higher `id` value, outer query calculates which of them is the most closest. PS. 2nd sq is nesessary only in case when the first record processed in 3rd sq is not valid - if both first and last records are valid, you can remove 2nd (aliased as hh) sq from FROM section and its linking condition from WHERE section.

Comment: That is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd531daf42376d384f40af46503ca6b1) with editions described in previous comment's postscript. And, of course, you can re-write it from cartesian to joins.

Comment: so, can i join the chron table to the output of your query and use it for the update?

Comment: how to modify the query in order to get not only the id of the closest, but the timestamp as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I suppose that `id` is ordered chronologically just like `timestamp` field.

```
UPDATE Chron AS w
   SET w.timestamp = IF( w.timestamp = D, @ts, @ts := w.timestamp )
 ORDER BY w.id ASC
;
```

The only requirement is that first (by `id`) record should have the correct timestamp.

Also that query update the broken timestamp to the value of the previous correct/corrected row and if you have the long continuous run of rows with broken timestamps result will be different from the "closest value". Anyway the "closest value" need a complicated query so "previous value" is good enough if you need some fast solution.

Comment: Is it correct to say that the timestamp of a row is set to the last timestamp different from D?

Comment: Yes it is. All timestamps equal to D will be eliminated. And if timestamp is not D it will be updated to itself (with @ts assinged to it too)